# Kivy error: Attribute error:'None type' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, file-io, kivy

Keep running into a error that says "Attribute Error: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'text'. I have no idea where the problem is. Did a fair amount of research, but saw no posts that provided any clarity on the issue. Thoughts?

This is my main.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import os
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class OptionMenu(GridLayout):

    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
            self.text_input.text = stream.read()
        self.dismiss_popup()   

    def show_save(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def save(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w') as stream:
            stream.write(self.text_input.text)

        self.dismiss_popup()
class GraphMenu(GridLayout):
    pass
class UnnamedMenu(GridLayout):
    pass

class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

class SaveDialog(FloatLayout):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)



class MainController(FloatLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        rt = MainController()
        return rt
Factory.register('Main', cls=MainController)
Factory.register('LoadDialog', cls=LoadDialog)
Factory.register('SaveDialog', cls=SaveDialog)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

This is my main.kv file:

```css
#kivy 1.0
<OptionMenu>
    cols: 2
 row:10
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.05
        text: "Input File"
        on_release: self.parent.show_load()
 Button:
  size_hint_y:0.05
  text:"Save File"
  on_release:self.parent.show_save()
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
  text:''
 RstDocument:
  text: text_input.text
  show_errors: True

<MainController>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Accordion:
            size_hint_x: 0.3
            orientation: 'vertical'
            AccordionItem:
                title:'Options'
                OptionMenu:
                    id: 'AppOpt'
   AccordionItem:
    title:'Config'
    UnnamedMenu:
     id:ConfigTab
   AccordionItem:
    title:'Graph'
    GraphMenu:
     id:GraphTab

        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_x: 0.7
            Label:
                
<scroller>

        
<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 10
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
<SaveDialog>:
    text_input: text_input
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: text_input.text = self.selection and self.selection[0] or ''

        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Save"
                on_release: root.save(filechooser.path, text_input.text)
```

This is the full error message and stack dump:

```css
botstrapping Kivy @ C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\
Setting Environment Variables:
#################################
GST_REGISTRY
C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\gstreamer\registry.bin
---------------
GST_PLUGIN_PATH:
C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\gstreamer\lib\gstreamer-1.0
---------------
PATH:
C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\;C:\Users\My.Files\Download
s\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27;C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-
win32\tools;C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\Scripts
;C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\gstreamer\bin;C:\Users\Adit
.Shah\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA Secu
rID Token Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Inte
l\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Window
s\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program F
iles\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\SAS\SharedFiles(32)\For
mats;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio
\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (
x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\
----------------------------------
PYTHONPATH:
C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy;
----------------------------------
##################################
done bootstraping kivy...have fun!\n
running "python.exe "D:\workspace\kivyWork\GUI\main.py"" \n
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\My.Files\.kivy\logs\
kivy_15-02-19_77.txt
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=
Nones
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout
=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout
=Nones
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, img
_gif (img_pil ignored)
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeo
ut=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeou
t=3600s
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)

[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Display driver windib
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual window size: 800x600
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual color bits r8 g8 b8 a8
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual depth bits: 24
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual stencil bits: 8
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual multisampling samples: 4
GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <4.2.0 - Build 10.18.10.3621>

[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <4.20 - Build 10.18.10.3621>

[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[DEBUG             ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG             ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG             ] [ImagePygame ] Load <C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.
0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, n
ot docked
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] Loading kv <D:\workspace\kivyWork\GUI\main.k
v>
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.loader> with limit=500, timeout
=60s
[INFO              ] [Loader      ] using a thread pool of 2 workers
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <textinput.label> with limit=None,
timeout=60.0s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <textinput.width> with limit=None,
timeout=60.0s
[DEBUG             ] [Atlas       ] Load <C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.
0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\data\..\data\images\defaulttheme.atlas>
[DEBUG             ] [Atlas       ] Need to load 1 images
[DEBUG             ] [Atlas       ] Load <C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.
0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\data\..\data\images\defaulttheme-0.png>
[DEBUG             ] [ImagePygame ] Load <C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.
0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\data\..\data\images\defaulttheme-0.png>
[INFO              ] [VideoGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.2.1.0
[INFO              ] [Video       ] Provider: gstplayer
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[DEBUG             ] [Base        ] Create provider from mouse
[DEBUG             ] [Base        ] Create provider from wm_touch
[DEBUG             ] [Base        ] Create provider from wm_pen
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO              ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[WARNING           ] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children

[WARNING           ] [Accordion   ] need 132px, got 100px
[WARNING           ] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.GraphMenu object at 0x07106A40> have no cols or r
ows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children

[WARNING           ] [Accordion   ] need 132px, got 100px
[WARNING           ] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.GraphMenu object at 0x07106A40> have no cols or r
ows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[WARNING           ] <__main__.UnnamedMenu object at 0x07106810> have no cols or
 rows set, layout is not triggered.
[ERROR             ] unable to access to <\hiberfil.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\uix\filech
ooser.py", line 122, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because i
t is being used by another process.')
[ERROR             ] unable to access to <\pagefile.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\uix\filech
ooser.py", line 122, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because i
t is being used by another process.')
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\workspace\kivyWork\GUI\main.py", line 76, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\app.py",
line 792, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\base.py",
 line 481, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\core\wind
ow\window_pygame.py", line 381, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\core\wind
ow\window_pygame.py", line 287, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\base.py",
 line 324, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\base.py",
 line 309, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\base.py",
 line 275, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_e
vent.c:4409)
   File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\uix\behav
iors.py", line 110, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "_event.pyx", line 312, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_e
vent.c:4359)
   File "C:\Users\My.Files\Downloads\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy\lang.py",
 line 1299, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "D:\workspace\kivyWork\GUI\main.kv", line 63, in <module>
     on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
   File "D:\workspace\kivyWork\GUI\main.py", line 34, in load
     self.text_input.text = stream.read()
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I remember getting an error like that because the Kivy interface changed from one version to the next; probably a function that used to return a value no longer did. You should paste the entire error message here so we can see the stack dump and line where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the value of `text_input`, so it is still the default `None`. Just setting an id doesn't set that attribute. There are a couple easy fixes here.

First, you can fill in that value:

```
<OptionMenu>:
    # this sets the `text_input` attribute to the value
    # of the `text_input` id below
    text_input: text_input
    ...
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can access the widget via the `ids` collection, and remove the `text_input` attribute completely:

```
def load(self, path, filename):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
        # self.ids is the collection of ids for this widget rule
        self.ids.text_input.text = stream.read()
    self.dismiss_popup()
```